# Nuxt JS use injected function from plugin in another plugin file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt JS's `inject` function to inject a function into my page for code reusability. I'd like to use the function in another plugin file and can't seem to get the function in there.

Here's my set up:

- **plugins/utils/tracking.js**

```js
function setCookiePrefix () {
  return 'fudge__'
}

function getCookie (app, name) {
  try {
    const prefix = setCookiePrefix()
    const cookie = app.$cookies.get(`${prefix}${name}`)

    if (!cookie || cookie == '') {
      throw 'cookie not set'
    }

    return cookie
  } catch (err) { }

  return null
}

export default function ({ app, store, context }, inject) {

  /*
  * Get just the affiliate (cpm_id OR affiliate)
  * examples: "my_brand", "blah"
  */
  inject('getAffiliate', () => {
    const affiliate = getCookie(app, 'affiliate')
    const brand = getBrand(store)

    if (!affiliate) return brand

    return affiliate
  })

}
```

And the file I'm trying to utilise the `getAffiliate` function in from my tracking.js file:

- **plugins/init-brand.js**

```js
export default async function ({ app, route, store }) {
  const affiliate = app.$getAffiliate()
  console.log(affiliate) <-- undefined
}
```

I've tried:

- `app.$getAffiliate()`
- `this.$getAffiliate()` <-- this works in a Vue file
- `$getAffiliate()`
- `this.getAffiliate()`

What am I missing to access my `getAffiliate` function in another plugin file?

Comment: Have you connected the plugins in the configuration in the right order? The plugin with the inject function should be higher in the ```plugins: []``` in ```nuxt.config.js``` to be available in the second plugin file

Answer (score 3):

I have an api plugin with some axios set up. I can load it inside another plugin file like this:

```
export default ( {$api} , inject) => {
  const service = new SomeService($api)
  inject('someService', SomeService)
}
```

So in your case that would be:

```
export default async function ({ app, route, store, $getAffiliate }) {
  const affiliate = $getAffiliate()
  console.log(affiliate)
}
```

Not sure if this is the right way, but it works for me.